# Wordpress post thumbnails (featured image) metabox not appearing in custom post

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I've enabled featured images with the following code:

```
if(function_exists('add_theme_support')){
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    set_post_thumbnail_size(145, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999, false);
}
```

and everything works fine except that I can't find the featured image metabox in my custom post editor. Under the "show" menu I only have the number of column and other 2 unrelated options. I'm on the last version of wordpress (3.1, I think?).

Can you help me? I've already tried everything I found on this website and elsewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found a solution: add the following code as a register_post_types function argument
    'supports'=> array('thumbnail')
this works but makes the part where you write the actual content disappear. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is inserting all this code in functions.php

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('events'));
```

(where events is the name of my custom post, you should use yours)

```
function create_event() {
    register_post_type( 'events',
         array(
            //...
            'supports' => array('thumbnail', 'title', 'editor')
                    //...
        )
    );
```

(thumbnail does the trick, but don't forget title and editor if you want to be able to have a title in your post or edit it!)

And last be sure to tick the box called 'thumbnail' - I suppose, my installation is in another language - under screen options (screen options is a button in the upper right corner, Google the name if you can't find it).